# How to simplify modulus expression?

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Currently I have

`4 - (X % (Y % (X - 4)))`

It looks like I can have a simpler term than this.
[image]

I just need last 4 rows to have 4, 3, 2, 1

Not sure whether there is a simpler equation!

Comment: @AlvinLepik `mod` could also be used to refer to the remainder operator (often denoted `%` in many programming languages).

Comment: @AlvinLepik sorry about the syntax, I took that from my code, do you know how I can correctly represent it ?

Comment: I don't think that you can simplify this as the modulo changes for different values of $X,Y$.

Comment: right, my bad, got tunnel vision because of the tags

Comment: If you don't care what the first six rows are just do $(10- x)\% 10$.

Comment: @Zanko Your stated expression of `4 - (X % (Y % (X - 4)))` doesn't match the values on the RHS of your table. For example, with $X = Y = 10$, it's true that $X \; \% \; Y = 0$, but $4 - (X \; \% \; (Y \; \% \; (X - 4)))$ doesn't. Note that $Y \; \% \; (X - 4) = 10 \; \% \; 6 = 4$, so $X \; \% \; (Y \; \% \; (X - 4)) = 10 \; \% \; 4 = 2$ and, finally, $4 - (X \; \% \; (Y \; \% \; (X - 4))) = 4 - 2 = 2$. However, your table shows it as being $4$ instead. Please clarify whether or not the expression you asked about is what you want us to try to help you with. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$Y\bmod (X-4)=X-k,k>4$$ Which means:$$X\bmod(Y\bmod(X-4))\equiv X-(X-k)\equiv k, \quad\text{if}\quad k\leq\frac{X}{2}$$

Which means half the time your value is $4-k$

The real problem, is dealing with finding k and working the other half of the time. Without a general use of variables, There's less chance that it can be put as something simpler in all cases.

Comment: One minor issue is that in your second line of calculations, you should say it's true for $k \lt \dfrac{X}{2}$. If $k = \dfrac{X}{2}$, then $X - k = \dfrac{X}{2}$ so that $X\bmod(Y\bmod(X-4))\equiv X\bmod \dfrac{X}{2} = 0$.